# Show RecycleView items count with ViewModel and LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'm making a expense_tracker app, but I run into some sort of problem.
I made a recycleview to show all history transactions and the next step is to show all transactions by a number.
I must make it with viewmodel and live data, but I can't figure it out how to check the transactions array when its changes and change the viewmodel data too...

Some of you have an idea for it?
Thanks.

Comment: Use the index of the array which is in the history's adapter then increment it by 1  , And display it with the other data in the item

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what I would do, is:

- Declare transactions list as a `MutableLiveData` of type `List<Transaction>` in `ViewModel`
- Observe the list from the fragment or activity so when it changes, i pass the data to `RecyclerView`'s `Adapter`
- Get the transactions from wherever you get them (API, DataBase ...)

If you want to filter the transactions, you declare the transactions list as a normal `List<YourTransactionModel>`, and declare the filtered list a `MutableLiveData`, so when you filter them you still have your full list, and use that to filter by anything you need, so you `observe` only the filtered list.